# Google Tango: Aligning Depth and Color Frames

Tags: google-project-tango

I would like to align a (synchronous) depth/color frame pair, using the Google Tango tablet, such that, assuming that both frames have the same resolution, each pixel in the depth frame corresponds to the same pixel in the color frame, i.e., I would like to achieve a retinotopic mapping. How can this be achieved using the latest C API (Hilbert Release Version 1.6)? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating simple crude UV coordinates to map tango point cloud points back onto source image (texture coordinates) - see comments above for more details, we've messed this thread up but good  :-( (Language is C#, classes are .Net)  Field of view calculate FOV horizontal (true) or vertical (false)

```
public PointF PictureUV(Vector3D imagePlaneLocation)
        {
            // u is a function of x where y is 0
            double u = Math.Atan2(imagePlaneLocation.X, imagePlaneLocation.Z);
            u += (FieldOfView(true) / 2.0);
            u = u/FieldOfView(true);
            double v = Math.Atan2(imagePlaneLocation.Y, imagePlaneLocation.Z);
            v += (FieldOfView() / 2.0);
            v = v / FieldOfView();

            return new PointF((float)u, (float)(1.0 - v));
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, this is great, thanks so much... I assume that the component values of imagePlaneLocation are direct copies from the xyz field of the TangoXYZij struct, right? Further, the actual pixel coordinates are computed through x = (u - cx) / fx and y = (v - cy) / fy, respectively, right?

Comment: Yes they are the points taken directly from the point cloud WITHOUT further transformation - it is a crude mapping, but it will get you going - more sophisticated mappings require accounting for lens distortion and a non-linear removal of Z -  by the way, it would help me if you mark one or more of these as answers if they helped you

Comment: @MarkMullin , Im a later comer but can you explain what is FieldOfView() , didn't understand that part properly ?.

Answer (score 1):

Mark, thanks for your quick response. Probably my question was a bit inprecise. You are of course damn right in saying that a retinotopic mapping between a 2D and a 3D image cannot be established. Shame on me. Nonetheless,
what I need is a mapping in which all depth samples (x_n,y_n,d_n), 1<=n<=N, N being the number of depth values, correspond to the same pixels (x_n,y_n) in the (synchronized) color frame. It is well taken that the depth sensor cannot provide depth information for troublesome areas in the visual field.

Comment: Ah -  if you take the point cloud and DON'T apply the matrix stack, then you've got XYZ as the basis vectors for the data -  this is what I use for texture application -  compute lens field of view on the horizontal and vertical axis, and now you can align the image from the camera with the point cloud - they'll be on top of each other - the real deal will be dividing out the Z, as math is perfect and lenses aren't

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks once again... But hmmm,I'm a bit a newbie on this... Using the camera intrinsics and using FOVx = 2 * atan(0.5 * width / Fx) and  FOVy = 2 * atan(0.5 * height / Fy), as given on [link](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics), I obtain FOVx=63.127079° and FOVy=38.110836° for the color camera and FOVx=63.126976° and FOVy=38.110699° for the depth camera, respectively. Where do I go from here? The image resolution of the color frames is 1280x720 and 320x180 of the depth frames.... A (pseudo) code snippet or a link to a tutorial would be great....

Comment: This is what I'm using right now -  it is lazy shoddy workmanship, but it works well enough -  you can mess about with how Z gets divided out, what I'm doing is admittedly blunt force trauma  --  (oh and the code is not efficient because the calcs really should be combined, but that means a day with a legal pad, a box of pencils, and the lens distortion coefficients - actual code added as new answer so as to format

Answer (score 0):

One of your conditions is not possible - there is no guarantee that tango will hand you a point cloud measurement of something in the visual field if it has trouble seeing it -  also there isn't a 1:1 correspondence between pixels and depth frame as the depth info is 3D

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but we can probably do: 
for each (X,Y,Z) from point cloud:

```
u_pixel = -(X/Z)* Fx, v_pixel = -(Y/Z)* Fy.
x = (u-cx)/Fx, y = (v-cy)/Fy.
```

for distortion correction (k1,k2,k2 can from distortion[] part of TangoInstrinsics, r = Math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2)))

```
x_corrected = x * (1 + k1 * r2 + k2 * r4 + k3 * r6) 
y_corrected = y * (1 + k1 * r2 + k2 * r4 + k3 * r6)
```

Then we can convert normalized x_corrected, y_corrected to x_raster, y_raster by using reverse of the above formula (x_raster = x_correct*Fx+ cx)