# How to convert TangoXyxIjData into a matrix of z-values

Tags: opencv, google-project-tango

I am currently using a Project Tango tablet for robotic obstacle avoidance. I want to create a matrix of z-values as they would appear on the Tango screen, so that I can use OpenCV to process the matrix. When I say z-values, I mean the distance each point is from the Tango. However, I don't know how to extract the z-values from the TangoXyzIjData and organize the values into a matrix. This is the code I have so far:

```
    public void action(TangoPoseData poseData, TangoXyzIjData depthData) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[depthData.xyzCount * 3 * 4];
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(
            depthData.xyzParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    try {
        fileStream.read(buffer, depthData.xyzParcelFileDescriptorOffset, buffer.length);
        fileStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Mat m = new Mat(depthData.ijRows, depthData.ijCols, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    m.put(0, 0, buffer);
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I would really appreciate help.

Comment: I guess this is Java. Could you add that tag in case I am not wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is it can't be done, at least not simply.  The XYZij struct in the Tango API does not work completely yet.  There is no "ij" data.  Your retrieval of buffer will work as you have it coded.  The contents are a set of X, Y, Z values for measured depth points, roughly 10000+ each callback.  Each X, Y, and Z value is of type float, so not CV_8UC1.  The problem is that the points are not ordered in any way, so they do not correspond to an "image" or xy raster.  They are a random list of depth points.  There are ways to get them into some xy order, but it is not straightforward.  I have done both of these:

1. render them to an image, with the depth encoded as color, and pull out the image as pixels
2. use the model/view/perspective from OpenGL and multiply out the locations of each point and then figure out their screen space location (like OpenGL would during rendering).  Sort the points by their xy screen space.  Instead of the calculated screen-space depth just keep the Z value from the original buffer.

or

3. wait until (if) the XYZij struct is fixed so that it returns ij values.

Answer (score 1):

I too wish to use Tango for object avoidance for robotics.  I've had some success by simplifying the use case to be only interested in the distance of any object located at the center view of the Tango device.

In Java:

```
private Double centerCoordinateMax = 0.020;
private TangoXyzIjData xyzIjData;
final FloatBuffer xyz = xyzIjData.xyz;
double cumulativeZ = 0.0;
int numberOfPoints = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < xyzIjData.xyzCount; i += 3) {
    float x = xyz.get(i);
    float y = xyz.get(i + 1);
    if (Math.abs(x) < centerCoordinateMax && 
        Math.abs(y) < centerCoordinateMax) {
        float z = xyz.get(i + 2);
        cumulativeZ += z;
        numberOfPoints++;
    }
}

Double distanceInMeters;
if (numberOfPoints > 0) {
    distanceInMeters = cumulativeZ / numberOfPoints;
} else {
    distanceInMeters = null;
}
```

Said simply this code is taking the average distance of a small square located at the origin of x and y axes.

centerCoordinateMax = 0.020 was determined to work based on observation and testing.  The square typically contains 50 points in ideal conditions and fewer when held close to the floor.

I've tested this using version 2 of my [tango-caminada](https://github.com/aroller/tango-caminada/blob/6970fd43cb8c1a60b03c1ffe68f96218a6fb2941/AreaLearningJava/src/com/aawhere/tango/TangoDepthCalculator.java) application and the depth measuring seems quite accurate. Standing 1/2 meter from a doorway I slid towards the open door and the distance changed form 0.5 meters to 2.5 meters which is the wall at the end of the hallway.

Simulating a robot being navigated I moved the device towards a trash can in the path until 0.5 meters separation and then rotated left until the distance was more than 0.5 meters and proceeded forward.  An oversimplified simulation, but the basis for object avoidance using Tango depth perception.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using camera intrinsics to convert XY coordinates to normalized values -- see this post - [Google Tango: Aligning Depth and Color Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693904/google-tango-aligning-depth-and-color-frames/28720753#28720753)  - it's talking about texture coordinates but it's exactly the same problem

Once normalized, move to screen space x[1280,720] and then the Z coordinate can be used to generate a pixel value for openCV to chew on.  You'll need to decide how to color pixels that don't correspond to depth points on your own, and advisedly, before you use the depth information to further colorize pixels.

The main thing is to remember that the raw coordinates returned are already using the basis vectors you want, i.e. you do not want the pose attitude or location